# Activity com.exe.sample has leaked IntentReceiver android.media.MediaPlayer$1@4123c640

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have two activities in my android application.I am playing video in video view in both the activities.When i move to second activity its started playing video on videoview. But when I return back to previous activity and try to interact with UI, I am getting:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered:
>   android.media.MediaPlayer$1@4123c640

And also I am getting:

> Activity com.exe.sample.Test1 has leaked IntentReceiver android.media.MediaPlayer$1@4123c640 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

in Second activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();

        }
    });
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test1.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Second Activity code:

```
public class Test1 extends Activity { private VideoView videoview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.tset);
    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
    videoview
            .setVideoURI(Uri
                    .parse(url));
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();

        }
    });

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add mp.release() in Test1.onStop().
the log show that 'android.media.MediaPlayer$1@4123c640' is a anonymous inner BroadcastReceiver class of MediaPlayer, it should be unregistered in MediaPlayer.release().

Comment: I could not set mp.release()

Comment: what you mean 'cloud not'

Comment: The receiver does not have a release() method. So it looks like this hint does not help.

Comment: I mean `unregister`